# Joomla Menu Customize

Tags: menu, joomla

How do I customize a Joomla Menu? I have a `MainMenu` with 1 row 1 item menu. I want to customize the menu with example style: 1 item 2 row. (each row each text field).

Now:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item-464">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-444 active deeper parent">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item-464">
        <a href="#">
            <span style="display:block">Home</span>
            <span style="display:block,font-size:10px">Home</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-444 active deeper parent">
        <a href="#">
            <span style="display:block">About</span>
            <span style="display:block,font-size:10px">About</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the items with a Parent Item of the first level in Menu Manager > Main Menu > Edit Menu Item which will create a menu tree as you add sub items.